# Install SQL Server (Express, compact, other?) in standalone pc

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, installation

Help needed here. I'm a bit lost checking all possible editions and configurations of SQL Server.

What I'd like seems straight forward: a version of SQL Server (ideally 2008, or higher), on a single PC (client+server), with a small footprint. I just want to self train in ddbb's basic administration (user creation, schemas, scripts, copying ddbbs, stored procedures).

These ddbb's won't be used with webs, other users, etc. Just myself, at most with an Access front-end linked to the SQL Server DB.

My doubts are:

1. Is is better **SQL Server Express 2008, Compact Edition (CE), SQL
   Lite**, something else ??
2. I would prefer using **SQL Lite** (seems the
       simplest), but my concern is how 'similar' (for things like schemas,
       permissions, scripts management, files names, **no worries** about multiple servers, though) is SQL lite to 
       a full SQL Server ?

I'd just like to familiarize with the basics in my pc so that when confronted to a real SSIS I can learn it quickly.

Thanks in advance,           p.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with SQL Express if you're planning to learn SQL Server. Although SQLite has a small footprint it is completely different from SQL Server. Queries to get and manipulate data are similar (but not identical in every manner), but everything related to metadata (schemas etc.) is completely different.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take the advice. A bit of bad news in the sense that I expected SQLlite to be easy enough, but not SQL Server express. Confused even about what setup I need to make it work.